# hp mini 110 3g not working

Tags: 12.04, networking, hp, 3g

I intstalled `Ubuntu 12.04` to my `HP` mini 110.
Everything working OK except my `3g modem`.
I read that others had driver issues but I think I have some other problem.

So after Ubuntu start it's asking my PIN code but after i type my PIN it's says `Network disconnected` when i try to connect again (clicking to `Mobile network ON`) it's says again `Network disconnected`. I think it's not trying to connect.
My PIN is okay (i have an external USB modem for testing, when i insert this SIM card to this modem it's working!)

The type of the internal 3g modem is `Hp lc2010 mobile broadband`.

Please help.

Thanks!

EDIT:
Finally i got the solution. Don't know that it's a HP mini 110 only or not but when the hardware Wifi button (F12) is turned off it's turning off the 3g too!
After i turned on the wifi and entered my pin it's found the network and the connect is success!

Comment: BTW it's asking for PIN but i can't see this hardware when i type lshw

Answer (score 0):

I recently solved similar problem on my Ubuntu by following this guide:
http://en.newinstance.it/2010/01/08/3g-usb-stick-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Yes i read that and many other topics about this but looks like i have a different problem. i tried this: sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x19d2 product=0x0031  but after that the problem is the some. Looks like it's throwing the "network disconnected" box before it's really trying to connect

Comment: i tried sakis3g too. It says my hardware but can't see any network. The automatic search of networks is failed and in the "manual select" part i can't see any networks! (as i sad it's working with an external modem so no real problem with network)